# how to get IP addresses Of LAN using JAVA

Tags: java, networking

I want to get IP address of my laptop that is connected into a LAN . This address has to be got from JAVA .

For this I have got the following code to get list of all IP addresses .

```
try
        {
            Enumeration e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while(e.hasMoreElements())
            {
                NetworkInterface n = (NetworkInterface) e.nextElement();
                Enumeration ee = n.getInetAddresses();
                while (ee.hasMoreElements())
                {
                    InetAddress i = (InetAddress) ee.nextElement();
                    String address; 
                    address = i.getHostAddress(); 
                    System.out.println(i.getHostAddress());
                }
            } 
        }
        catch( SocketException SE)
        {
            SE.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now I have got the following list of IP addresses .

```
127.0.0.1
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
192.168.10.99
fe80:0:0:0:4c55:cf87:67a0:2%10
192.168.115.215
fe80:0:0:0:a972:d8d9:c94c:4263%11
fe80:0:0:0:707c:b434:bf95:4940%12
192.168.15.1
fe80:0:0:0:1d59:66f7:e68e:31d%15 is reachable
fe80:0:0:0:1d59:66f7:e68e:31d%15
192.168.38.1
fe80:0:0:0:553f:f180:b540:75ff%16
```

But how can I get my LAN IP address ? My lan ip address is  192.168.10.99 .

Comment: For this your application needs to know the name of the interface which is connected to your lan. Or you decide that the first private network address you find is your local lan. Or you define a variable with the network address of your local lan and the adapter with an address inside this network is your local lan ;)

Comment: I have assumed that the first private network address you find is my local lan .

Answer (score 1):

This conde snippet helps me a lot .

```
 String IP()
    {
        String IP_address = "";
        int count = 0 ;
        try{
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (interfaces.hasMoreElements())
            {
                NetworkInterface current = interfaces.nextElement();
              //  System.out.println(current);
                if (!current.isUp() || current.isLoopback() || current.isVirtual()) continue;
                Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = current.getInetAddresses();
                while (addresses.hasMoreElements()){
                    InetAddress current_addr = addresses.nextElement();
                    if (current_addr.isLoopbackAddress()) continue;
                    if (current_addr instanceof Inet4Address &&  count == 0)
                    {
                        IP_address = current_addr.getHostAddress() ; 
                        System.out.println(current_addr.getHostAddress());
                         count++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(SocketException SE)
        {
            SE.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return  IP_address;
    }
```